Spring-Context upgrade for version 6.1.15 failing with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for WebAsyncManager.isMultipartRequestParsed()
Issue is with the spring-context WebAsyncManager which is not able to find the method
c.f.h.l.w.s.e.UniformExceptionResolver   : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.isMultipartRequestParsed()

This error occurs only when we perform the delete operation on the mockmvc request below. Instead of receiving a 201 http status code, we end up with 500 httpstatus, which end up as assertionError.
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/v1/test/"+testId+"/roleTest/"+roleTestId))
        .andExpect(status().isAccepted());

The delete api internally calls the the application endpoint and check for isMultipartRequestParsed method which it was not able to find.
Does this method is present in any higher version than spring-context version 6.1.15 and above. For me it seems its missing from spring-context version 6.1.14 and 6.1.15 or any alternate method has been introduced to address this fix?

Never mix jars from different versions of a framework. If you are upgrading 1 module you need to upgrade all modules. Else you will run into compatibility issues. With Spring Boot (which according to the tags is what you are using) you shouldn't be messing around with individual Spring modules, but either upgrade Spring Boot (which is tied to spring versions) or at least specify the Spring version for all modules (which is as simple as adding <spring.version>6.1.15</spring.version> to your properties section in your pom.
